# Firebase Push notification in Flutter Application in iOS Device doesn't work

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up a Flutter application with push notifications for Firebase, but when i try to send it, nothing happens on my iPhone.
I followed all the steps listed on the official guide (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)
and i've tried many solution found on the web but they didn't work. On my Android device all works correctly.
This is my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBkkfrO5WWC2ZYg9cCsG0xgkJKi69hw43U")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I added this inside Info.plist file

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

and enabled background process and push notification in Runner under Signing & Capabilities
[image]

I checked TeamID and KeyID correspondence between Firebase and AppleDeveloper Platform.
Does anyone know what could be the solution or have any suggestion on possible tests to spot the problem? Thanks